# C# DispatchTimer WPF Countdown Timer

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that includes a countdown timer, I'm stuck with the formatting part of it, I have little to no experience with programming and this is my first time using c#. I want to countdown from ***15 minutes*** using DispatchTimer, but as of now, my timer only counts down from ***15 seconds***, any ideas?

My countdown timer so far:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int time = 15;
     

        private DispatcherTimer Timer;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
            Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            Timer.Start();
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (time > 0)
            {
                time--;
                TBCountDown.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
                
            }
            else {
                Timer.Stop();
            }
        }
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach would be to do it with a `TimeSpan` rather than an `int` with a number. Setting the `TimeSpan` value in the following application will do the countdown as I want.

`TimeSpan.FromMinutes` for minutes

`TimSpan.FromSeconds` for seconds

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) for more detailed information.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    TimeSpan time;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (time == TimeSpan.Zero) dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        else
        { 
            time = time.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1));
            MyTime.Text = time.ToString("c");
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
   <Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="MyTime" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialise the DispatchTimer with an interval of 1 second: `Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);`
And every TimerTick you decrement your `time`field.

So, `time`should start of with the total number of seconds you want to count down. If you start with 15, your countdown timer will count down from 15 seconds to zero.
If you want it to count down for 15minutes, you have to initialise `time` to 900 (15 x 60'').

Comment: Thanks for the help, this would work but I'm looking to get the format something like this: 15:00